# How to export comments section in podio using API

Tags: java, excel, export, podio

basically I just want to know, if there are ways on how to export excel sheet file in Podio with the comments section included in a certain app using API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct API call to export to excel along with comments. Export work on Items and Apps

There is a work around to do this. 
1. Make a CommentAPI call as per code attached, you can get all the comments on Item, so that you can export them to your excel programmatically.

```
public class APICall implements Serializable {
public static void main(String as[]){
    APICall  apiObj =  new APICall();
    apiObj.apicall();
```

}

```
/**
 * 
 */
public void  apicall()
{
    try{
    System.out.println("inside");
    ResourceFactory resourceFactory = new ResourceFactory(new OAuthClientCredentials("<WS NAME>","<Your authkey>"),new OAuthUsernameCredentials("<username>", "<Password>"));
    CommentAPI capi = new CommentAPI(resourceFactory);
    Reference ref= new Reference(ReferenceType.ITEM,561530318);
    List<Comment> cmts = capi.getComments(ref);
    for(Comment e : cmts )
    System.out.println(e.getValue());
```